# Data Abort Exception for write access on POP with ARMv7

Tags: assembly, arm, armv7

When you use the MMU on ARMv7-A CPUs like in my case the Cortex-A9 you can configure access permissions for sections and pages.

When an access violation has been detected by the MMU a data abort exception is triggered. In general, the cause of this data abort exception (e.g. access violation or an alignment fault) is described in the Data Fault Status Register (DFSR) in CP15.

In the DFSR the type of access, i.e. write or read, and the fault status are given. At the moment I am observing the following: I get a data abort exception and the DFSR is telling me that the type of the access was a write access and the fault status field tells me it was an access violation.

So far so good. But when I look at the instruction that supposedly caused the abort, it is the following:

```
    S:0x01038628 : POP      {r4,pc}
```

How can this be a write access? If I remember correctly, it is a synonym for:

```
    LDMIA SP!, {r4, pc}
```

so there is no write access at all? How can this instruction cause an access violating write access?

Comment: There are several sources of information.  The **DFAR** is the address of the fault; Ie, the memory access that caused the abort.  If you are looking at the *dabort* link register, then that is the PC+8 where the *write fault* triggered the CPU.  However, it is possible that some sort of speculative write happens.  Look at all the registers (DFAR, IFAR, DFSR, IFSR and exception LR).  Where did you get **0x01038628** from?  Data abort `lr` must be adjusted by *-8*?